# Where is the "Outline elements" function in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer

I cannot find the "Outline elements" function in developer tools of Internet Explorer 11 (in older versions it was placed in the [Outline menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565626(v=vs.85).aspx#outlineMenu)).

Was it removed from the IE11 or is it just hidden somewhere I have not found it?

Answer (score 19):

Looks like it's been redesigned somewhat.  The DOM Explorer tab has three icons underneath it. Two of the icons split up the behavior I think you're looking for.

The first is the Select Element icon, which looks like an edit box with a Ouija pointer.  When you click it, you'll see selection rectangles around objects in the webpage as you use the mouse to hover over them.

The second icon, a series of boxes, is the DOM element highlighting switch.  When it's active, you can click elements in the HTML tree and they'll highlight on-screen.

This is hinted at, but not directly discussed, in the [updated documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255008(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Thanks. I know the "element highligting switch" but it is not exactly I'm looking for since it higlights just the selected elements. The former "Outline elements" function did highligting of all specified elements (usually TDs and THs) on the table. It was good for debugging old-style table layout of pages.

Comment: I don't think it's there any more; I think they redesigned the tools and that feature didn't make the cut.  You could see if restoring the feature has been added to the User Voice forum (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform) and, if it has, vote it up.  If it hasn't, you could add it and encourage others to vote it up.

Comment: thank you @LanceLeonard. is it possible to highlight an element from the console? I mean if I do something like document.getElementByID('foo'). can I click on the result and see it highlighted somehow?